# Whatsapp group chat invite link not working

Tags: firefox, hyperlink, safari, whatsapp

I have a button that links to a Whatsapp group chat via the group's invite links `https://chat.whatsapp.com/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx`

During testing, the redirects fail in Safari (11) and Firefox (60).
Safari does not even open a new tab, and when I manually paste the URL in the navbar it gives the following message:

> Safari can't open 'whatsapp://chat?code=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
> because macOS doesn't recognize Internet addresses starting with
> 'WhatsApp:'.

On Firefox, the message is:

> The address wasn’t understood
>
> Firefox doesn’t know how to open this address, because one of the
> following protocols (WhatsApp) isn’t associated with any program or is
> not allowed in this context.
>
> You might need to install other software to open this address.

(note that in both cases the URL is different from the `href` of the button...)

Any ideas of what might be causing this and any possible workarounds?

Comment: have you solved the issue?

Comment: @ta2-1 Nope, unfortunately. I'm working on a different project now, but last time I checked about two months ago, I was still having this problem...

Comment: We probably need more information to understand the problem and possibly help. How are the redirects invoked? Can you still reproduce the problem?